# Shunting-yard algorithm for expression parser

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, math-expression-eval

After reading about the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), I decided to try to make a expression parser, before trying to make a actual language parser, using it. The way i translated the algorithm into C++ code seems pretty compact, so  there is really not much code to post:

### Shunting-yard algorithm(in C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include "list.h"

bool isInteger(char &c) {
    return (c >= '0') && (c <= '9');
}


int main() {
    std::vector<char> output;
    List<char> stack;
    List<char>::iterator it = stack.begin();

    std::string expr("2-2*3/6");
    std::map<char, int> op_precedence;
    op_precedence['+'] = 10;
    op_precedence['-'] = 10;
    op_precedence['*'] = 20;
    op_precedence['/'] = 20;

    for (char &c : expr) {
        if (isInteger(c)) {
            output.push_back(c);
        } else {
            if ((stack.size() > 0)) {
                if ((op_precedence[stack.top()] >= op_precedence[c])) {
                    output.push_back(stack.top());
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(c);
                } else if ((op_precedence[stack.top()] < op_precedence[c])) {
                    stack.push(c);
                }
            } else {
                stack.push(c);
            }
        }
    }
    for (it = stack.begin(); it != stack.end(); it++) {
        output.push_back(*it);
    }

    for (auto &i : output) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing I should note, is that the `list.h` I include, is not part of the standard library. That is a linked list class I finished up a few hours ago. If the code for the linked list is really necessary, I'll post it, but I don't think it will. I pretty much behaves like a normal linked list. In fact, you could exchange it with the standard linked list. Just replace `pop()` with `pop_front()`, `push()` with `push_back()`, and `stack.top()` with `stack.front()`.

I also should mention that I have not included parenthesis yet, as I'm just trying to get the basics down first.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use a range based loop in the second last loop?

Comment: @miscco that was my bad. I forgot that you didn't have to implement a 'in' operator, for your custom classes.

Comment: I think you are missing a while loop - read this [code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail).

Comment: @ChristianDean A beginner question: What should I substitute top() for when I use the standard linked list?

Comment: Hey @Holyprogrammer sorry for the very late reply. To answer your question, assuming you are using the standard linked list class like a stack, `list::front` should give you want. The "top" (i.e. first element) of the linked list.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks a lot!! :) I have edited your question accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **`isInteger`** is not needed. Use `std::isdigit`.
- Trust the logic. An `else if` condition is mutually exclusive with `if` condition. There is no need to test for it - you already know it is true. A simple `else` is enough. But see also the next point.
- Notice that all code paths in the `else` clause necessarily `push(c)`. Factor it out:

  ```
  if ((stack.size() > 0) {
      if ((op_precedence[stack_top()] >= op_precedence[c])) {
          output.push_back(stack.top());
          stack.pop();
      }
  }
  stack.push(c);
  ```

Comment: Excellent answer vnp, thank you. But if I was going to use `string`'s instead of `char`'s, wouldn't I have to make a my own `isdigit()` function? Or is there a standard library function for that too.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry Unless I misread the question, the best way to parse an integer from the string is to call `strtol` or something in its family, and analyze the end pointer.

Comment: Oh no. In my question I am working with characters. your answer is in the correct context. I was asking if I would have to make my own function to test if a **string**  is an integer. Or if there is some standard library function for already. I'll check out `strtol` though. Thanks.

Comment: @vnp Just Curious, but what can I use in place of the top() function when using standard linked list?

Comment: One comment on this.  With only two precedence levels, this works as is.  However, if you plan to extend it to three or more precedence levels, as I did when trying to produce a micro C parser, you should change `if ((op_precedence[stack_top()] >= op_precedence[c]))` to `while ((op_precedence[stack_top()] >= op_precedence[c]))` so it handles `1 + 2 * 3 & 4` correctly: you need to unwind both the `*` and the `+` on the stack before pushing the `&`.  Other than that, this is one of the most clean and simple to understand implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm I've ever seen.